# EmberJS: How to find which controller is used to drive .hbs view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have inherited a codebase and trying to make sense of what is what. In emberjs application how do I know which controller (js) corresponds to a view (hbs) on a particular page. Is there a setting? Is there a convention?

Comment: http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/post  here you can get clear picture

Answer (score 1):

The convention is that their names (or more accurately their paths) should be the same.

As in, `controllers/page.js` should have a `templates/page.hbs` and a `routes/page.js`

You can see this convention if you create a new Ember project using `ember new` or [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/).

You can also specify the template name within a route using the [`templateName`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/classes/Route/properties/templateName?anchor=templateName) property.

```
// routes/page.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  templateName: 'something/different'
});
```

Ember also allows us to use the [`renderTemplate`](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html?anchor=renderTemplate&show=inherited,protected,private,deprecated&type=method#) hook within our routes and pick a different template and/or a different controller.

```
// routes/page.js
export default Route.extend({
  renderTemplate(controller, model) {
    // Render the `something/else` template
    // and use the and `other/thing` controller
    this.render('something/else', {
      controller: this.controllerFor('other/thing')
    });
  }
});
```

[Read more in "Ember JS Guides: Rendering a template"](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/routing/rendering-a-template/)

Ember also used to allow embedding templates within other templates using the `partial` helper.

It would matter a lot which Ember version you are using because that would restrict your concerns to a certain API behavior, since Ember did change a lot through the years.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it's pretty simple. Ember follows convention over configuration so let's learn the convention. The algorithm is as follows.

1. Look at the current url that you are on. In this case, we are on `/foo`
2. Open up the `router.js` file and find the route that matches this url pattern. If you don't specify `paths` then the url will just be the name of the route, but you could also be dealing with nested routes. Let's say we found route named `foo.js` which would be under `appName/routes/foo.js`.
3. Open the route file. Routes jobs are to fetch data in the `model` hooks, and then to set the variables on the corresponding `controller` instance via the `setupController(controller, model)` hook. When not specified, this method just sets the entire model object on the controller. Now we should have a decent idea of what variables have been dynamically set on the controller.
4. Open the controller under `appName/controllers/foo.js`. The best way to think about controllers is they are the single source of state for the corresponding template (`appName/templates/foo.hbs`). Their values are set via hooks on the route, as well as through the `init` method, computed properties, observers, etc. When you reference any `{{variable}}` in a handlebars template, the controller that matches this portion of the page's context is the source of state that resolves this variable. If the controller isn't defined, then Ember autogenerates one for you. Worth noting that controllers are singletons and their state persists between route changes.
5. Open the template.hbs file to see your markup. You might have components (custom html-looking tags that take attrs) which store their javascript under `appName/components/component-name.js` and their templates in `appName/templates/components/component-name.hbs` or have no template if the javascript file can just specify a `tagName` and that's it.

One other quick thing: routes are invoked in a parent/child hierarchy and correspond to urls via the route. The top level route is the application route. If you look in it's template, you will find an `{{outlet}}` Ember will then find whatever child route comes next and render its template into this outlet. by default `/`, the `index` route's template is rendered. But if the url was `/foo` then `foo.hbs` will be rendered into the application's outlet. Foo.hbs can have an outlet, and thats when we start getting into nested routes. That's about as quick/high level overview as I can give, ask any questions if you want specifics (I love Ember)